# Animation between Activities, of which one is singleTask

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm developing a chat app and am having trouble with figuring out how to get the transition between two activities to animate correctly. I have googled this for a while now and have also searched SO for it, but sorry in advance if this question has already been answered.

I have a `ChatMainActivity`, which holds a Fragment containing a list of chats and a `ChatContentFragmentActivity`, which holds a Fragment containing the chat messages. As seen below I have declared the ChatMainActivity as `launchMode="singleTask"` in my AndroidManifest.xml.

```
  <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.ChatMainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
  <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.ChatContentFragmentActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".ui.activities.ChatMainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

These are my animation .xmls:

`chat_content_activity_enter_animation.xml`

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/activity_animation_duration"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

`chat_content_activity_exit_animation.xml`

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/activity_animation_duration"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

`chat_list_activity_enter_animation.xml`

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/activity_animation_duration"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

`chat_list_activity_exit_animation.xml`

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@integer/activity_animation_duration"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

And here is how I use them:

In the `Adapter` of the `RecyclerView` containing the chats in `ChatMainActivity`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatContentFragmentActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.chat_content_activity_enter_animation, R.anim.chat_list_activity_exit_animation);
```

`ChatContentFragmentActivity`

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.chat_content_activity_exit_animation, R.anim.chat_list_activity_enter_animation);
}
```

My Problem now is that the enter and exit animations of the `ChatContentFragmentActivity` are shown, but the `ChatMainActivity` does nothing.

There was a SO question that I can't seem to find now, that suggested, that singleTask was a problem here, but I remember the solution suggest in that question not helping me.

Does anyone know how I can get the exit and enter animation of my `ChatMainActivity` to play?

Edit: This is how it looks at the moment:[image: Animation at the moment]

Comment: @sushildlh see my edit for a .gif showing how it is working (wrongly) at the moment

Comment: use this link http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/tutorial-activity-slide-animation/#more-483 and improve your knowleadge also ... enjoy coding

Comment: I tried what they did in that tutorial but it unfortunately didn't help and yielded the same results as seen in the `.gif`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this .

pull_right.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    />
```

push_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

use in the Adapter this........

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatContentFragmentActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_right, R.anim.push_left);
```

use this in the ChatContentFragmentActivity Class `onBackPressed()` method.......

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition( R.anim.fade_out,0);
    }
```

and for keyboard just add these line in your xml file in `EditText` Tag of ChatContentFragmentActivity ....

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

enjoy coding ..........

Comment: Although I managed to get it to work in the meantime, this also would have been a viable solution, so I'll accept your answer.